# C++ Builder 2009 Synchronize

Tags: c++, synchronization, c++builder, c++builder-xe2, c++builder-2009

I need a method to run on the main thread in `C++ Builder 2009`. Reading http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize it looks like they added the `Synchronize` functionality in `XE2`. Is there a way to do this in `C++ Builder 2009`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it looks like they added the Synchronize functionality in XE2

I do not know where you got that idea from, but `TThread::Synchronize()` has existed in the RTL as long as `TThread` itself has existed.  Originally `Synchronize()` was a non-`static` method, so you could only call it from a live `TThread` object.  A `static` version was added in Delphi 7 (during the time when C++Builder was dead, so it did not appear in C++ until C++Builder was resurrected in 2006), and anonymous procedure support was added in Delphi/C++Builder 2009.  So, `TThread::Synchronize()`, both static and non-static versions, most definitely exists in C++Builder 2009, which you can verify if you look at the declaration of the `TThread` class in `Classes.hpp`.